# Exchange on WINDOW operation when the data is already partitioned and exchanged

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the query below which is **EXCHANGING** data to perform row_number() over a COLUMN on which the data is already exchanged in both the data sets

the table **crime_parquet_table** is a **Bucketed** table on the column **Incident_Number** with **30** buckets

```sql
explain
select
*
from
(
select  *,
row_number() over(partition by Incident_Number order by Incident_Number) as rnk
from
    (
        select  *
    from
        (
        select /*+ REPARTITION(30,Incident_Number) */ * 
        from austin_crime_data_new
        union all
        select *
        from crime_parquet_table
        ) tmp
    )t
) d
where rnk = 1
```

below is the explain plan.
I believe the +- Exchange (7) is not necessary.
Let me know if you guys think otherwise and the reason for the same.

```
== Physical Plan ==
* Filter (10)
+- Window (9)
   +- * Sort (8)
      +- Exchange (7)
         +- Union (6)
            :- Exchange (3)
            :  +- * Project (2)
            :     +- Scan csv  (1)
            +- * ColumnarToRow (5)
               +- Scan parquet default.crime_parquet_table (4)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this worked using the below alternative approach
as union all doesn't look at this as a special case . it just treats this as any other tables

So first I saved my intermediate data also as a bucketed table

```sql
create table crime_parquet_table2
using parquet
CLUSTERED BY (Incident_Number) INTO 30 BUCKETS
location 'path2'
select /*+ REPARTITION(30,Incident_Number) */ * 
from austin_crime_data_new
```

Now I create a table using **LIKE** with both paths ( each have bucketed data)

```sql
CREATE TABLE crime_data like crime_parquet_table2
location 'path1,path2'
;
```

Now the sql on this new table gives the expected plan

```sql
explain
select *
from
(
select * ,
row_number() over(partition by Incident_Number order by Incident_Number) as rnk
from crime_data
) 
where rnk = 1
```

**PLAN**

```
== Physical Plan ==
* Filter (5)
+- Window (4)
   +- * Sort (3)
      +- * ColumnarToRow (2)
         +- Scan parquet default.crime_data (1)
```

So the extra work is persisting the intermediate data to a storage but shuffle is eliminated